# I have a variable that i need to send to php to be written to a file

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a specific array that php needs to access and write to a file. I also want to be able to call the php to get the array info back. I use JSON.strigify to store the array in a string, but i cant figure out how to send it to a server with php. I have very little php experience and i tried:

```
<script language="javascript">



var COMMENTS_FOR_DISPLAY = new Array('Have fun with this code: Chris');

// Adds a new comment, name pair to the Array feeding textualizer.
function add_comment() {
  // Retrieve values and add them to Array.
  var new_comment = $('#kwote').val();
  var new_name = $('#name').val();


   COMMENTS_FOR_DISPLAY.push(new_comment + ': ' + new_name);


  // Reset <input> fields.
  $('#kwote').val('');
  $('#name').val('');

  var arrayAsString = JSON.stringify(COMMENTS_FOR_DISPLAY);

}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var txt = $('#txtlzr');  // The container in which to render the list

  var options = {
    duration: 5,          // Time (ms) each blurb will remain on screen
    rearrangeDuration: 5, // Time a character takes to reach its position
    effect: 'random',     // Animation effect the characters use to appear
    centered: true        // Centers the text relative to its container
  }

  txt.textualizer(COMMENTS_FOR_DISPLAY); // textualize it!
  txt.textualizer('start'); // start
});
</script>
```

in main.php i put:

```
<?php
$kwoteString = $_GET["arrayAsString"];
echo $kwoteString;
?>
```

I used echo to see if i was getting any output,but i wasn't. It could be a very simple fix, maybe im missing a header or something telling my html document to read main.php?? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're missing this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Ummmm...what does this have to do with PHP or JSON?

Comment: ajax is required to communicate between client side and server side via HTTP Requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a hiddenField and set the string to the hidden field. 
php code will read the value from hidden field.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery with 
$.post(url,params);

there are many tutorials around the web and stack overflow itself.

Here the doc:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/